# Limitar caracteres en consulta y rellenar espacios con otro caracter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito hacer algo con respecto a una consulta, les explico:

Tengo 3 columnas de las que necesito armar un dato:

- una es llamada Prefijo.
- la otra llamada contador.
- y la ultima llamada longitud.

Con estas 3 necesito armar un conteo para un comprobante, en mi país los tenemos estructurados así: `B0100000000`.

Entonces:

- la parte de **B01** es el prefijo
- la longitud es lo siguiente después de eso (los 8 ceros) y el contador es el numero de comprobante.
- la casilla de longitud esta porque necesito que sea de longitud variable, ya que no solo personas de mi país usaran esa modalidad, por lo que necesito que se adapte a distintas partes del mundo, por lo menos de LATAM.

En pocas palabras necesito armar el comprobante de estas 3 columnas y no caigo como hacerlo.

Se me ha recomendado este método, para hacer el trabajo:

```
RIGHT(@Prefijo + @Contador, @Longitud)
```

No me termina de agradar, por lo que quiero ver que otra cosa puedo hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Opción 1:  Usar FORMAT

Podes hacerlo así:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(@Prefijo, FORMAT(@Contador, CONCAT('D', @Longitud)))
```

Donde:

- [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) la usamos para concatenar las cadenas.
- [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) la usamos para dar formato al valor de la variable `@Contador` indicando [el formato `D`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#standard-format-specifiers) + `@Longitud`

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @Prefijo VARCHAR (3) = 'B01',
  @Contador INT = 1,
  @Longitud INT = 8

SELECT CONCAT(@Prefijo, FORMAT(@Contador, CONCAT('D', @Longitud)))
```

Resultado:

```
B0100000001
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/191473)</kbd>

---

### Opción 2:  Usar REPLICATE

Podes hacerlo así:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(@Prefijo, RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', @Longitud), @Contador), @Longitud))
```

Donde:

- [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) la usamos para concatenar las cadenas.
- [`REPLICATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) la usamos para crear una cadena de `0` de longitud igual a `@Longitud`.
  **Nota**: El resultado de `REPLICATE('0', @Longitud)`, dependiendo del contexto, se podría almacenar en una variable y evitar tener que crearla todo el tiempo.
- [`RIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) la usamos para obtener, empezando desde la derecha, una cadena cuya longitud sea igual a `@Longitud`.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @Prefijo VARCHAR (3) = 'B01',
  @Contador INT = 1,
  @Longitud INT = 8

SELECT CONCAT(@Prefijo, RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', @Longitud), @Contador), @Longitud))
```

Resultado:

```
B0100000001
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/191491)</kbd>

Comment: Pero eso hará más lento el proceso porque FORMAT es una función ineficiente.

Comment: Hola @LuisCazares, diría que todo depende de cuantos registros se van a procesar.